# File download using Selenium ChromeDriver in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a piece of Selenium code(Java) to automatically download a file (xlxs) and send it via email to a list of recipients.

I have integrated this in Jenkins using Mavens and I get to the step where I can push a button to download the file however the file is not to be found in the workspace or anywhere on the server.

I want to get the file to attach it in an email, using Jenkins and send it.

When I do this locally, the file is being downloaded automatically in the default "Downloads" folder however on the server side it doesn't do the same.

Any advice on where this file is being downloaded or how can I specify the download folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Update the question with your code.

Comment: The code does what needs to do(pressing the button to trigger the file download), I don't see the benefit of adding the code here. What I need to do is be able to send the file to a certain folder in order to attach it to an email using Jenkins.

Comment: you may not see the merit of adding the code , but people on SO who answer the questions do! Having code along with your question has multiple advantages such as: 1. it saves us from suggesting something that you may have already tried saving everyone some time, 2. it shows us that you have done your fair share of research before asking the question and most importantly 3. You are more likely to get quality answers when you give all the information to solve the problem. I could have tried to answer your question but instead I had to write this comment

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I use Firefox, so my code is bit different.

you can specify the download folder or use existing customizated browser profile

using temporary browser profile:

```
FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = new FirefoxProfile();
selenium_profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);    
selenium_profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\BP_usr_tmp\\");
selenium_profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
```

using existing profile:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
    FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
    options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that the file goes here :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\used_version
```